# Internal webcam not detected on Samsung Galaxy book 3 pro running Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: webcam, samsung, 23.04

My internal webcam is not detected by ubuntu 23.04.
Ubuntu is installed on an external ssd (Samsung T7 500GB) and i am using a Samsung Galaxy Book 3 Pro

I tried a lot from the web. I run Windows 11 on the laptop mainly and there the webcam works. No hardware issue here.

My laptop has a key for blocking webcam which does work on Windows but on Ubuntu has "no function". If I press it nothing happened. After relaunching the application or reboot nothing worked with the key.

I tried to open the webcam with Cheese and Microsoft Teams. If I connect an USB C webcam like the logitech streamcam it works fine. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an external SSD for testing and that did not work either.

My sound doesn't work either (though that's a separate issue).

If I run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` the message I get is `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.`

I tried `lspci -nnk` but there is no webcam detected

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a707]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:a7a0] (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a71d]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal_pci
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci

00:05.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a75d]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]

00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a74d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a76e]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a72f]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a74f]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]

00:0d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a71e]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:0d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a73e]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Device [2222:1111]
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

00:0d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a76d]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Device [2222:1111]
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

00:10.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #2 [8086:51d8] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:12.0 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub [8086:51fc] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller [8086:51ed] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:51ef] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller [8086:51e0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:519d] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51ca] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller [8086:51a3] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller [8086:51a4] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller [144d:c882]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5017] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Sandisk Corp Device [15b7:5017]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

If I run `sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices` the output is `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.`

From `ls -l /dev/video` the output is `ls: cannot access '/dev/video': No such file or directory`

The command `ls -l /dev/video0 ;id` gives me the output `ls: cannot access '/dev/video0': No such file or directory uid=1000(andre) gid=1000(andre) groups=1000(andre),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),100(users),118(lpadmin)`

Comment: Could you please post some information about the webcam? A quick search on the net on your computer model did not reveal any details.

Comment: Still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to enable the Webcam in bios

Or maybe you need to give it permission

I'm not sure but try :

```
sudo chown root:video /dev/video0

sudo chmod 666 /dev/video0
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you're out of luck ( assuming it's the same OV02C10 sensor that's in my Book 3 Pro 360. ) There is work ongoing to make the new Intel IPU6 connected cameras function [here](https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers), but they're a long way off being in the mainline kernel and that OmniVision sensor is one that doesn't yet seem to work - I've been playing around with the driver and have managed to get the device to be recognised, but without the datasheet for various register and clock settings I'm stuck for now.

Bottom line is that unless someone with both the appropriate motivation *AND* the appropriate data comes along you may be waiting a while - so an external webcam is the only way to go for now.